# auth0 User is not authorized to the audience for those scopes

Tags: auth0, auth0-delegated-admin

Context: I am hitting the `/oauth/token` endpoint, using the `Resource Owner / Password` authentication flow.

Observations: Previously this was working just fine. Now, without any code or configuration changes, auth0 is returning with a 400 and an error response body: `{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"User is not authorized to the audience for those scopes"}`

Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Hi @efreezy - this is a known issue & a fix should be available v.shortly.

Comment: @arcseldon Thank you for the quick response! Where can I check for the status of the issue? https://status.auth0.com/ lists all systems operational.

Comment: Hi. Fix has already been applied - please can you recheck.

Comment: fyi only - official status here - http://status.auth0.com/incidents/ttky8gz6xptv

Comment: Everything is working as expected. Thank you.

Comment: Great to hear, and thank you for your patience, help with notification, and testing. much appreciated!